# Greasemonkey - Use one user scripts from other user scripts (as a js library)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I need an universal js library to use it in other user-scripts.

Is it possible to use one user script from other user scripts in Greasemonkey?

What is the @require syntax for the such cases? Or, maybe, there is an other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the library script on a website, you can `@require` it just like you'd `@require` any other script.

Another option is to allow extensions local filesystem access, and then you can link the needed the scripts to the one local library version, eg:

```
// @require          file://C:/SomeLibraryScript.user.js
```

A third option would be to enable the library script on all pages (eg `// @match        *://*/*`), make sure it runs as soon as possible, have it assign its functions to some property of the window, and then have other userscripts use that window property to call it.

A fourth option is to create your scripts with a module bundler like Webpack and have all scripts that need the library just import the library from its file location, [like I do here](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/common/showToast.ts).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, CertainPerformance!
1) It haven't a sense: this is a remote script, not a GM user script (but may be used as a last chance);

Comment: 2) Greasemonkey won't save a test script with the reason: "Script save error | null at file:///C:/test.js | The editor contents have not been saved. Fix this error and try again." (I was trying file://C:\test.js , file://C:/test.js , file:///C:/test.js ). Other possibility to use a localhost webserver, but it's also not a GM user script.

Comment: 3) It may work, but it will be not stable (because of the asynchronous loading of scripts);

Comment: 4) I don't understand - is it a variation of browser addons or remote scripts?

Comment: (1) But you said *Is it possible to use one user script from other user scripts* - are you now saying that the script you want to use as a library actually *isn't* a user script? But if it's a remote script, that should make `@require`ing it easier, right?

Comment: (2) This is not an issue with Greasemonkey, this is some other issue. If you cannot save files onto your own hard drive, you have more serious problems to worry about. Try debugging it.

Comment: (3) If you have your library script run as soon as possible, as I said in the answer (run it at the beginning of page load) it should be trivial for your other scripts that depend on it to have it loaded in time. Worst-case, you could dispatch a global event other scripts can listen to, but that's trivial too

Comment: (4) This is how pretty much all professional JS is written nowadays. You install Node and NPM on your computer, create a package, and then require/import the files you need. See the repository link in the answer for an example. You'll write the JS as you need to in separate files, then build it together into a single userscript for distribution like here: https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/One-Click-VTC/dist/StackOneClickVTC.user.js